# How to Select a Column In A Google Document Table Using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Setup:

I have a Google Form sending data to a Google Sheet. The Google Sheet does some calculations natively. I then use App Script to send the calculated values as a table in a Google Document.

Issue: there is no way (that I am aware of), to select a column of the "table" variable and apply attributes to the column only.

What I would like to do: something similar to table.setColumnAttributes(1, style)

```
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = "DO NOT CHANGE";   // name of sheet to use
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  //get the last r and column of data
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn();
  
  // define the range containing the data
  // this can be changed depending on which columns to embed
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,8,12,4);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation()); 
  
  // note - this is a change mentioned in 
  // Embed Google Spreadsheet table Withing Google Document when data contains dates
  // when the data includes a data, "getValues()" fails hence
  // changing the method to "getDisplayValues()"
  var values = range.getDisplayValues(); 
  
  // get the document details
  var docid = "*************DOCID************";
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var ranges = doc.getNamedRanges('embeddedSheet-range');
  
  if (ranges.length == 0) {
    Logger.log("DEBUG: ranges is zero")
    var table = body.appendTable(values);
  }
  else {
    Logger.log("DEBUG: ranges is NOT zero")
    tableRange = ranges[0];
    table = tableRange.getRange().getRangeElements()[0].getElement();
    var ind = body.getChildIndex(table);
    tableRange.remove();
    body.removeChild(table);
    table = body.insertTable(ind, values);
   
   
    table.setColumnWidth(0, 60);
    table.setColumnWidth(2, 60);
    table.setColumnWidth(3, 60);

    var style = {};
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
    var test = table.getChild(1);
    test.setAttributes(style);

  }
  var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
  rangeBuilder.addElement(table);
  doc.addNamedRange('embeddedSheet-range', rangeBuilder.build());
}
```

I don't see any default way to set a certain column's attributes (color, font size, etc). (You can natively set the column width using table.setColumnWidth, but not other attributes)

The following code (from above), highlights a row, but still lost on how to get a column

```
    var style = {};
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
    var test = table.getChild(1);
    test.setAttributes(style);
```

Comment: Most of code above is from the following: https://itectec.com/webapp/google-apps-script-automatically-update-inserted-sheets-cells-in-google-docs/

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine ["Document Structure"](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure#structural_elements). We see that the table object does not have direct column child object. So we should update style of each cell in a column consequently. For example, the first table and the 4-th column style is modified in the following way:

```
function setTableColProperties() {
  const COL_INDEX = 3;
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#0000cc';

  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var table = body.getTables()[0];  // the table for styling
  for (var i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
    table.getCell(i, COL_INDEX).setAttributes(style);
  }
}
```

[table.getCell() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table?hl=en#getCell(Integer,Integer)) is useful to access the same column cells.